# how to calculate 24?

Tags: python, algorithm

I wrote a python script trying to solve the 'calculate 24' problem, which originated from a game, drawing 4 cards from a deck of cards and try to get the value 24 using +,-, *, and /.

The code is working, only that it have many duplications, for example, I input 2, 3, 4, 5 to get the value of 24, it will find and print that 2*(3 + 4 + 5) is 24, but it will also print 2*(5 + 4 + 3), 2*(5 + 3 + 4), etc., while it will find 4*(3 + 5 - 2), it will also print 4*(5 + 3 - 2). Could anyone please give me some hints on how to remove duplicated answers?

The code is as follows:

```
def calc(oprands, result) :
    ret=[]
    if len(oprands)==1 :
        if oprands[0]!=result :
            return ret
        else :
            ret.append(str(oprands[0]))
            return ret
    for idx, x in enumerate(oprands) :
        if x in oprands[0:idx] :
            continue
        remaining=oprands[0:idx]+oprands[idx+1:]
        temp = calc(remaining, result-x)         # try addition
        for s in temp :
            ret.append(str(x) + ' + ' + s)
        if(result%x == 0) :                      # try multiplication
            temp = calc(remaining, result/x)
            for s in temp :
                ret.append(str(x) + ' * (' + s + ')')
        temp = calc(remaining, result+x)          # try subtraction
        for s in temp :
            ret.append(s + ' - ' + str(x))
        temp = calc(remaining, x-result)
        for s in temp :
            ret.append(str(x) + ' - (' + s + ')')
        temp = calc(remaining, result*x)          # try division
        for s in temp :
            ret.append('(' + s + ') / ' + str(x))
        if result!=0 and x%result==0 and x/result!=0 :
            temp = calc(remaining, x/result)
            for s in temp :
                ret.append(str(x) + ' / ' + '(' +s +')')
    return ret

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    nums = raw_input("Please input numbers seperated by space: ")
    rslt = int(raw_input("Please input result: "))
    oprds = map(int, nums.split(' '))
    rr = calc(oprds, rslt)
    for s in rr :
        print s
    print 'calculate {0} from {1}, there are altogether {2} solutions.'.format(rslt, oprds, len(rr))
```

Comment: You're going to need to figure out what it means to you for two answers to be "really the same". Are you going to want `(8+4)*(4/2)` and `(8+4)/(2/4)` to be considered the same? What about `((8+4)*4)/2` and `(8+4)*(4/2)`? Even after you solve the commutativity problem, I suspect you're going to run into a lot of similar problems with deciding whether two solutions are different enough to be interesting.

Comment: So, I guess, your meaning is that, I need to use combination on addition and multiplication, because these two operations are not order sensitive, and use permutation on subtraction and division, because these two operations are order sensitive?

Comment: That's not what I'm saying, though it could help. I'm saying that after you fix this problem, you might realize it's only the easy part of a tougher issue. You might be satisfied with just solving this part, though.

Comment: Also, your code never comes up with solutions like `(5+1)*(3+1)`, so it's not working as well as you probably want it to. You'll need to change how you search for solutions if you want to address that. There's also at least one puzzle that requires the use of fractional intermediate results: `8 8 3 3`, for which I believe the only solution is `8/(3-8/3)`.

Comment: yeah, you are right, thanks a lot for pointing out, there needs some modification in how to search for results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Calculate 24* is an interesting and challenging game. As other users pointed out in the comments, it's difficult to create a solution that doesn't present any flaw.

You could study the [Rosetta Code (spoiler alert)](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/24_game/Solve#Python) implementation and compare it to your solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link, the Rosetta Code is cool, am going to study how they implemented it. This code has some flaws, I would like to post a new code if it at least could find all solutions, let aside duplications.